# Russian (Cyrillic) tags?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

As the site is about Russian language should it allow Russian tag names (that is cyrillic names)?

The [German SE](http://german.stackexchange.com) has tags in German, but do cyrillic letters make things different?

Comment: `french.SE` has also switched over to French tags and `spanish.SE` has decided to go Spanish too, with the [switch-over partly accomplished](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/231/the-great-slu-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012) so far. `japanese.SE` has [discussed Japanese tags in the past](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16/do-we-need-support-for-kanji-tags) but it doesn't seem to be on the table currently.

Comment: the tag I added above is entirely frivolous and taken from kotekzot's answer; please feel free to remove it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that they do. I tried to retag this question by adding 'дискуссия', and the tag disappeared as soon as i hit space. This seems to be a problem. [Here's the feature request/bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135929/add-cyrillic-support-for-tags) to have support for Cyrillic tags added, support it!

**Update:** SE inc. employee has confirmed that Unicode support for tags is in the works, but is still some time away.

Comment: You cannot create tags, your reputation is too low. But let's wait for this until we have moderators! :)

Comment: @Alenanno but I can type. When I type "asd" into the retag box it shows up as a tag, when I type "фыв" it disappears.

Comment: Oh you're right. The rep limit is lower... Try asking on MSO! :)

Comment: @Alenanno thanks, I did. Here's the question, support it if you like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135929/add-cyrillic-support-for-tags

Answer (score 5):

This is now enabled on russian.stackexchange.com and meta.russian.stackexchange.com, however please note that **you're the first**. This means it is entirely possible that there's one or two bugs hiding in the corners, waiting to pounce.

If you see any issues in the behavior of your tags (whether cyrillic, ascii, or other), please let me know directly.

Comment: Great, thanks Marc!

Answer (score 4):

I think they should be allowed, but they shouldn't duplicate the existing English tags. We could consider synonymizing them, but as a rule duplication should be avoided.

Comment: I expect a fair number of our users aren't going to be able to come up with appropriate English tags, so synonymization is a must. Which direction we go with (English tag+Russian synonym or vice versa) should depend on which language is more prevalent on the site.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of Russian tags, however IMHO they should be used only where strictly necessary. As an example of proper use, I'd welcome tags `ё` or `тс-vs-ц`. However we should not use Russian words to name general topics, like stress, consonants etc. because this would make it hard for foreigners to use the site. My opinion is that this site should be as non-Russian-speakers-friendly as possible. There are many good Russian-language resources on Russian and very few non-Russian ones.

This doesn't mean that Russian askers are not welcome here, on the contrary. But we should have a clear set of guidelines, and tagging is one of the mechanisms to enforce them.

Comment: The french.SE has converted their tags etc to all French, and the spanish.SE is begun such a transition too. Not that I'm for or against it, just letting everybody know what's happening out there.

Comment: @hippietrail Thanks for pointing it out. I think we should also try to take into account the differences between different languages, nations, probable users of the site, and the personal intentions of the active community. I can see the difference between Russian and French for example. May be my idea about the purpose of this site is different from other people here. I live outside Russia and want to promote our language. I've also seen many foreigners struggling with it and having no good resources to help them. Obviously from inside Russia the point of view will be different. Let's discuss

Comment: I can see that the different script could be an extra barrier, at least for ease of reading, on top of the different language. I've known Cyrillic for years but I still read it much more slowly than Latin script even for languages I don't know. I guess other people will have the same?

Comment: @hippietrail That's interesting! The idea of the script didn't come to my mind. I actually was talking more about the role of the language in the world, and the attitude of people (native speakers and learners) to it. You're right, there is also an interesting issue about the alphabet. Germans find it impossible to understand that ы is one letter :)