# Cyrillic tags - now on a site near you!

Tags: discussion, tags

As Marc said [here](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/220/8), we have enabled support for Cyrillic tags on this site.

This means you should now go and create some tags in Russian. :) Propose some tag wikis and excerpts as well.

You are the first site that's getting this feature, so there may be some bugs lurking around. If you run into any issues either with the Cyrillic tags or with the plain old English tags, please let us know right away. You can post any issues you find in this thread.

Other than that, enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Is it technically possible to relate Russian and English versions of the tags?

So that if you tag a question `etymology` it would also automatically be tagged `этимология`? I don't see a reason to maintan both, though Russian tags as such would be great to have.

Comment: We can set up synonyms for tags that mean the same thing. You (as a community) can decide whether you want the English or the Cyrillic version to be primary.

Comment: @AnnaLear and Quassnoi: I asked Gilles for the French SE and he said they have *"tag names in french, with english synonyms. Bilingual tag wiki"*.

Comment: @Alenanno I see that a bunch of synonyms have been created, but they are directed the other way: from Russian to English. You might want to open a meta post to hash out a policy here.

Comment: @AnnaLear I was going to do something to start the translation (deciding the official ones with the community)... but since there is no automatic way to extract the tags, I'll have to do that manually, and that takes some time. :(

Comment: @Alenanno You can get your community to help you build a list of tags that could be translated. ;)

Comment: @AnnaLear I honestly didn't think of that. :P

Comment: @AnnaLear [List and question created](http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/q/226/71) :)

Answer (score 1):

Wonderful. I've also asked other language site mods about their policy on bilingual tags, so we already have a starting point. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think we should have primary tags in Russian with English synonyms, except for (hypothetical) cases when there's no Russian version of the tag.  The issue will be around whether/how it would be possible to change an existing tag into a synonym for another tag.  Additionally, For example, if we have tag *conjugation* and questions tagged with it, when we create tag *спряжение*, will we be able to simply change existing tag *conjugation* to be the synonym of *спряжение* without negative impact on the tagged questions (and, preferably, without manually re-tagging all questions)?

Finally, some English tags may correspond to more than one meaning in Russian, in which case we'll need to be careful as to how we set up synonyms.  I can't think of a specific example right now though.